# actual value stored in a bool variable if a large value is assigned

Tags: c++, type-conversion

what would be the value stored in a bool variable if I assign a value greater than 1 to it?

```
bool mySwitchVariable = false;
mySwitchVariable = 3;
if(mySwitchVariable == 3){
    cout << "3 is stored in the bool" << endl;
}
```

is this defined in spec?
can this behavior be compiler dependent?

Thanks

Comment: Any value other than zero is assumed to be `true`. _" can this behavior be compiler dependent?"_ Not really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bool is a standard defined build-in type. It supports assignment from numeric types for C compatibility.

When assigning a numeric value different than zero the bool variable becomes true. When assigning zero, it becomes false.

> 4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool] 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value,
>   or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is
>   converted to true. For direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is false.

Comment: so (mySwitchVariable == 3) is true, no matter what numeric data was assigned? would (mySwitchVariable == 2) also be true? wondering if the "2" be converted to "true" before doing "=="

Comment: @Solti (mySwitchVariable = 3)... The (mySwitchVariable == 3) will be false (equality). Any non zero value will be converted to true when assigned to a bool variable. Regarding the equality, in general both operands have to have the same type, so the mySwitchVariable == <numeric> will always be false. There are some conversions when dealing with pointers, but this is not the case.